# How to avoid vba script from removing template row colors?

Tags: excel, vba

My vba script removes template default colors after copy paste into sheet2. My code should have simply selected cells and set numbers over default color cells. Any special comments, positive feedback would really be appreciated from any guru wizard.

```
Sub Copy2()

Dim LastRow As Long
Dim NEWFORMAT As Worksheet

Set Results = Sheets("NEWFORMAT")
LastRow = Results.Cells(Results.Rows.Count, "Z").End(xlUp).Row

Range("B50:J75").Copy
Results.Range("A" & LastRow + 61).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
Range("C30:D37").Copy
Results.Range("D" & LastRow + 105).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll

Application.DataEntryMode = False
End Sub
```

Comment: Change `xlPasteAll` to `xlValues`

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlpastetype

Comment: Wonderful! It worked perfect. Thank you special Guru.

Comment: @ Siddharth Rout Thank you for the positive feedback!  Microsoft, docs.